# cannot find runtime/cgo in Alpine

Tags: go, alpine-linux

In an `alpine:edge` container I installed go via

```
RUN apk add --no-cache musl-dev go
```

I try to run `go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go` then.

This results in the error message:

```
go: finding github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go latest
go: finding github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.1
go: downloading github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.1
go: extracting github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.1
# github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
loadinternal: cannot find runtime/cgo
protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
```

Now looking at the code, it fails on `ctxt.PackageFile[name]`.

I double checked though, that both `/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cgo` and `/usr/lib/go/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime/cgo.a` are present.

Which should all be in order according to `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build521273293=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Anyone any hints where to look next or what is wrong?

Comment: should you do `install` instead of `run`?

Comment: You mean using `go install` instead of `go get`? Doesn't change the error message.

Comment: I'm not sure what alpine is doing with the go package, but I would generally avoid OS distributed go packages for development. At some point you're going to want to decouple the go version from the OS version, as the stable OS packages will quickly fall out of date.

Comment: Agreed. On the other hand building Go from scratch clutters Dockerfiles a bit too much.

Comment: That's where I use multi-stage builds. Make your base image like `golang:1.12-alpine` and build off that. I usually go one further and build the app in another intermediate stage, ending with a container that doesn't need the go installation at all.

Comment: IIRC, Alpine doesn't ship with GCC by default, it doesn't use glibc even (musl I believe). You're installing musl-dev, but if you want GCC, you'll have to install `build-base`, first (`apk add build-base`). Either way, the error seems to suggest your `GOROOT` doesn't contain the standard packages, specifically `runtime/cgo`, That said: 2 stage docker builds FTW

Comment: While multistage may be an easy thing to do for (nearly static) go - it gets really ugly for other types of software (*cough* _protoc_ *cough*), which uses way more disperse cluttered files.

Answer (score 4):

One way to avoid this issue is to force a static build disabling `cgo`. Try building your binary with the following command:

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o yourBinaryName
```

If you actually need cgo in your app, you might want to install gcc, musl-dev and  even build-base like @abergmeier pointed out.
You can do this with this command:

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache musl-dev gcc build-base
```

If none of that works I would check out this gist claiming it creates a Dockerfile capable of compiling protobuffs: ["Alpine (3.6) based docker image with Protocol Buffers compiler supporting Go"](https://gist.github.com/rizo/513849f35178d19a13adcddf2d045a19)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than *work-around(s)* the **correct** solution is to install what the `go` compiler is *actually* looking for.

The error:

> cannot find runtime/cgo

basically at a high level means it cannot find the necessary libraries and headers on your system to link against any C code or C libraires.

Just install what it is looking for `libc-dev` in this case with:

```
$ apk --no-cache -U add libc-dev
```

Or if preferred just install the meta package `build-base`:

```
$ apk --no-cache -U add build-base
```

Answer (score 0):

For now as a workaround, I copy necessary Go binaries from `golang:1.12-alpine` into my current container.

With that, `go get` works as intended.