# Problem extracting object file while cross-compiling using 'go build'

Tags: go, osdev, go-build

I'm trying to create a go.o object file that I'll link using external linker. I followed the [gopher-os](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8T3VxGrrJwc&t=1200s) procedure to extract object file.

main.go:

```
package main

func main() {

}
```

Makefile:

```
go.o:
    mkdir -p build
    GOARCH=386 GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -n main.go 2>&1 | sed \
        -e "1s|^|set -e\n|" \
        -e "1s|^|export GOOS=linux\n|" \
        -e "1s|^|export GOARCH=386\n|" \
        -e "1s|^|export CGO_ENABLED=0\n|" \
        -e "1s|^|WORK='build/'\n|" \
        -e "1s|^|alias pack='go tool pack'\n|" \
        -e "/^mv/d" \
        -e "s|-extld|-tmpdir='build/' -linkmode=external -extldflags='-nostdlib' -extld|g" \
        | sh 2>&1 | sed -e "s/^/  | /g"
```

When I invoke `make go.o`, I get the following message in the terminal:

```
  | loadinternal: cannot find runtime/cgo
  | /usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008049000
```

The **go.o** file does get created in the `build/` directory, but any further use of that file does not lead to successful results further in my work.

I have tried setting `CGO_ENABLED` to `0` and `1` but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: This looks like an cross compiling issue, wich sometimes happens when copile from Windows to linux.

Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932233/cannot-find-runtime-cgo-in-alpine

Maybe this will help.